# New motherboard, can't connect to eno1

Tags: networking, ethernet, lan, motherboard

When trying to connect to my access point router upstairs, I struggled too long before I realized that my computer simply wasn't recognizing my ethernet connection. It will connect to the wifi just fine, and I can connect my laptop to ethernet, but not my pc. I recently switched out my motherboard, and I want to rule out that it's hardware based.

I ran this, as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118850/no-wired-ethernet-connection) and this is what it shows:

```
$ sudo ethtool eno1

Settings for eno1:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: on (auto)
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: yes

$ sudo dhclient eno1

/etc/resolvconf/update.d/libc: Warning: /etc/resolv.conf is not a symbolic link to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf

$ sudo lshw -c network -sanitize

  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I217-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 00
       serial: [REMOVED]
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:26 memory:f7800000-f781ffff memory:f783c000-f783cfff ioport:f080(size=32)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: adding output:

```
$ sudo ifconfig

eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fc:aa:14:e4:74:ce  
          inet6 addr: fe80::feaa:14ff:fee4:74ce/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3955 errors:0 dropped:9 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:43 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:413445 (413.4 KB)  TX bytes:6041 (6.0 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7800000-f7820000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5501 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5501 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:946892 (946.8 KB)  TX bytes:946892 (946.8 KB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.30.1.26  P-t-P:10.30.1.25  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:23005 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15986 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:25277107 (25.2 MB)  TX bytes:1607393 (1.6 MB)

wlxbcec23c36593 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr bc:ec:23:c3:65:93  
          inet addr:192.168.0.207  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2b13:56a1:3bc3:17c9/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:73958 errors:0 dropped:245 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:42374 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:87738456 (87.7 MB)  TX bytes:11852387 (11.8 MB)
```

EDIT 2: adding outputs:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto dsl-provider
iface dsl-provider inet ppp
pre-up /bin/ip link set eno1 up # line maintained by pppoeconf
provider dsl-provider

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet manual

$ sudo cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml

cat: '/etc/netplan/*.yaml': No such file or directory
```

EDIT 3: adding outputs:

```
$ ls -al /etc/resolv.conf

-rw-r--r-- 1 root eric 52 Aug 16 12:20 /etc/resolv.conf

$ cat /etc/resolv.conf

nameserver 209.222.18.222
nameserver 209.222.18.218
```

Comment: Please add the output of `ip a` or `ifconfig`

Comment: Please [edit the question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1267559/edit) to show us the complete output of `ip addr`

Comment: Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Is this a Desktop or Server installation? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: The device is called `eno0`. `eth0` doesn't exist

Comment: @MaxSilvester thank you

Comment: @heynnema updated

Comment: You didn't use the complete command for `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Please let me see that. Thanks!

Comment: We need to fix /etc/resolv.conf. Edit your question and show me `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Did you switch your motherboard with an identical make/model? If it was significantly different you may need to reinstall the OS. This is best practice anyway with a significant hardware change like a new CPU and especially a new motherboard.  For example: the new motherboard might not have the same Ethernet adapter.

Comment: @Nmath same brand (Gigabyte) but different model. Perhaps you are right. It's probably time I did that anyway.

Comment: Sorry, but we don't support Mint here. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**/etc/resolv.conf**

You've changed the /etc/resolv.conf from a symlink to a hard-wired file with DNS servers for your VPN. This is incorrect. It also means that without VPN up, web sites won't be able to find their IP addresses.

We should set things back:

`sudo rm -i /etc/resolv.conf` # delete the current file

`sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf` # recreate the original symlink

**Note**: And if there are any DNS resolution problems with/without VPN, we'll troubleshoot those later.

---

<strike>**Edit /etc/netplan/*.yaml...**</strike>

`ls -al /etc/netplan/*.yaml` # find the filename

`sudo -H gedit /etc/netplan/filename.yaml`

And make sure it only contains this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Then in the `terminal`, type:

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

---

**Edit /etc/network/interfaces...**

`sudo -H gedit /etc/network/interfaces`

Change this line:

```
iface eno1 inet manual
```

To:

```
iface eno1 inet dhcp
```

Then in the `terminal`, type:

`sudo ifconfig en01 up`

or

`sudo ip link set eno1 up`

or

`reboot`

---

**MTU**

You have a problem with the MTU=1500 setting for your DSL connection.

There's a MTU setting in Ubuntu's network configuration, and a WAN MTU setting in your router.

For DSL, a common MTU setting is 1492. Just go ahead and try this value first and see if your web sites are now accessible.

To determine the correct setting, start with all MTU settings = 1500 and VPN = off. (VPN requires different testing).

In the `terminal`:

ping [-c count] [-M do] [-s packet_size] [host]

The options used are:

- `c count`: number of times to ping
- `M hint`: Select Path MTU Discovery strategy.  may be either `do` (prohibit fragmentation, even local one), `want` (do PMTU discovery, fragment locally when packet size is large), or `dont` (do not set DF flag).
- `s packet_size`: Specifies the number of data bytes to be sent.

You should always start at 1472 and work your way down by 10 each time. Once you get a reply, go up by 1 until you get a fragmented packet. Take that value (last good value) and add 28 to the value to account for the various TCP/IP headers. Eg. let's say that 1452 was the proper packet size (where you first got an ICMP reply to your ping). The actual MTU size would be 1480, which is the optimum for the network we're working with.

`ping -c 4 -M do -s 1472 8.8.8.8` # this will probably show fragmentation

`ping -c 4 -M do -s 1462 8.8.8.8` # may show fragmentation

`ping -c 4 -M do -s 1452 8.8.8.8` # no fragmentation?

`ping -c 4 -M do -s 1453 8.8.8.8` # still no fragmentation?

reference: [How to determine the proper MTU size with ICMP pings](http://muzso.hu/2009/05/17/how-to-determine-the-proper-mtu-size-with-icmp-pings)

Comment: Added requested outputs. I can get to the rest later this evening. A potentially consequential note, I have had my VPN on through this. Should I disable?

Comment: @Eric Please keep me posted. What version Ubuntu?

Comment: @Eric First get it to work without VPN. VPN troubleshooting can come later.

Comment: Mint 18.1 cinnamon 64-bit

Comment: Should I simply reinstall the OS before I go through all this, or will that not solve the problem?

Comment: @Eric Don't reinstall the OS yet. Try the /etc/network/interfaces portion of my answer. That might be all it takes. Also, technically, we don't support Mint here, only Ubuntu... but since I've already written an answer... report back.

Comment: I have web connection now, and my VPN connects, but oddly, my network manager applet shows "no connection". Thanks for your help and sorry I posted in the wrong place.

Comment: @Eric Did the /etc/network/interfaces part of my answer get you online again?

Comment: Yes it did. Should have clarified.